# Phantom Suggested Edit

Tags: bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of items needing review is a lie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165647/number-of-items-needing-review-is-a-lie)

Using the review tool at

https://stackoverflow.com/review

I constantly see 1 Suggested Edit. Clicking on Suggested Edits shows

> There are no items for you to review.

I can do this over, and over, and over to the point where the probably that someone keeps grabbing the 1 suggested edit before I do is vanishingly small.

When there are N (where N > 1) Suggested Edits, I can go in and review (N-1), after which I'm told there are no more.

If I go back to https://stackoverflow.com/review I see 1 Suggested Edit again.

Is there a phantom suggested edit or possibly a broken counter?

I started noticing that this afternoon PST.  This morning it was fine.

**UPDATE**

Now there appear to be 3 phantom Suggested Edits to review.

Comment: [Mission accomplished](http://xkcd.com/810/).  Seriously, though, the interest that the suggested edit queue attracts (and the velocity by which suggested edits get reviewed) is a good thing, even if the occasional robo-acceptance is not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm still seeing the problem (but with just 1 phantom in the system).

Comment: I see 0 suggested edits pending...

Comment: And I still see 1.  Funny.

Comment: Probably a dumb question. Is there any possibility that you have setup a filter in suggested edit queue recently and you forgot to clear it?

Comment: @ACB: If it were a filter, the message would say that no review items matched your filter criteria. It makes it pretty clear that your lack of reviewable items is due to the filter you're using. :)

Comment: @ACB: I do not have a filter setup.

Comment: @animuson, Thanks for clarifying it. That was a wild guess. :)

Comment: The counter in the main /review page appears to show cached number. Not a good idea if you ask me!

Comment: @ShadowWizard, it seems I have the same problem (4 years after)... does it worth a question?