# Late Answer Review Doesn't Load

Tags: bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review First Posts stuck on “loading item” Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165512/review-first-posts-stuck-on-loading-item-firefox)

For the past hour or so, there has been 1 Late Answer available to me for review.

Clicking on the late answer shows the message

> loading item

which persists "indefinitely" (at least 2 minutes).

If I abort by clicking the Review link again, an orange error box flashes up that starts with

> An error occurred when loading the review item

I have been able to reproduce this 5 times over the last 20 minutes.

Possibly related to [Phantom Suggested Edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165515/135806) but the symptoms are different.

**UPDATE**

The duplicate this points to claims that the issue is fixed "in the next build."  That statement was made last October.

Either the "next build" is not out 4 months later, or this is a recurrence of the issue.

Comment: You need to reopen the one this is linked to. *That* one is closed as a duplicate of a bad one. No need to reopen this one. It's still definitely a duplicate.