# Number of items needing review is a lie

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

For some time now on SO's [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) page it has said there is 1 Late Answer and 1 Low Quality post needing review even though there isn't any.

[image: review count]

This image is a lie.

- The items in these queues QUICKLY disappear. After a moment this should have gone down to 0 after a refresh.
- It says 1 even though when I attempt to review the item it continues saying there is nothing to review.
- I have the queue open in one tab and the main review page open in another tab while I ctrl+F5 both pages constantly.

Something isn't right...

**Update:** Now it is stuck at 2 and 1. It had said 3 for Late Answers, it allowed me to review one and then it said "no items to review" however it says there are still 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed now.

Review audits are randomly created on the fly, but if a person abandons an audit (e.g. closes the tab), then it hangs around in the database for the next unlucky person. A recent bug caused these abandoned audits to be included in the overall counts.

Comment: Zombie attack!!